# django-import-export package : CATEGORYL1 invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'TOP'

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, django-import-export

I am trying to upload a .xlsx file and store the data into db using django-admin panel. The package I am using is django-import-export. Data is Uploaded almost successfully but there is one error related to foreignKey field i.e. : "CATEGORYL1 invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'TOP'"

Here is my code for models.py,resources.py and admin.py repectively

```
#models.py
from django.db import models

class ParentCode(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class CategoryL1(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class CategoryL2(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Item(models.Model):

    ItemCode=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ItemName=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    CategoryL1=models.ForeignKey(CategoryL1,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    CategoryL2=models.ForeignKey(CategoryL2,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    UPC=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ParentCode=models.ManyToManyField(ParentCode,blank=True)
    MRPPrice=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    Size=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Enabled=models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

```
#admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from .models import Item

# Register your models here.
@admin.register(Item)
class ViewAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    pass
```

```
#resources.py
from import_export import resources
from .models import Item

class ItemResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields=('__all__')
```

screenshot of: [The excel sheet Im trying to upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBNbF.png)
.
.
screenshot of erro :
[django-admin after uploading data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRQoB.png)

Comment: For your `Item` model categories are foreign keys where in your excel file it's strings. You need to pre-process uploading with replacing categories names with appropriate FK's.

Comment: @Charnel can you please elaborate? I already tried to upload Preprocessed excel sheet with categories column as integer(Primary id of categories).still not working. :(